# Determine when a buffer has been played without polling the source in OpenAL

Tags: objective-c, c, openal

Is this even possible? Would be extra cool if somehow I manage to have a function called every time a buffer has been processed. Any other ideas besides polling the source it's welcomed :D

Comment: Did you mean polling the source?

Comment: +1 Indeed I did, sorry about that, I've edited the question

Comment: Here's something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046315/getting-notified-when-a-sound-is-done-playing-in-openal

Comment: and this, which seems to say no: http://opensource.creative.com/pipermail/openal/2009-April/011616.html

Comment: Yes, I think it's not possible, still I wonder, would it be resource wise comparing with polling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know how many samples are in each buffer and you know the sample rate that the source is playing at.  That should give you a pretty good idea of when the source will finish processing a buffer.

If you're feeling very intrepid, you could hack this into the OpenAL-soft source.  By the looks of the code, you would put the change into `mixer.c` at the very end of the file, somewhere near the end of the `MixSource()` function.

Remembering, of course, that OpenAL-soft is lGPL; so you'd need to release/make available any changes that you made to the library itself.

If you're stuck using pre-included libraries, then you don't have many options.  OpenAL rejects the idea of callback functions.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying JCooper, however, I don't know if I can touch this implementation of OpenAL (iOS). If I could, would knowing the sample rate and the number of samples on each buffer help me as long as the actual processing it's processor dependent? (could take more or less).

Comment: I doubt you can change the iOS version of OpenAL, but I think you can make it use OpenAL-soft as a plugin, or something.  I'm not sure what you mean with the rest of your comment.  The length of time taken to process a sound buffer should be more-or-less processor independent.

Comment: I choose your answer because even if for iOS won't work (I end up polling the source), maybe it helps someone else that works o a different platform! Thanks!