# iOS API method to ask whether a sound loaded and started by the app is still being played

Tags: ios, audio, sdk, status, playback

Is there a method provided by the iOS SDK to allow the application to start a loaded sound, and know when it is finished or still being played?

I'm using [this](http://stormyprods.com/SoundEngine/) audio library but it lacks that kind of functionality

These are the functions I've been using

To load a sound effect or background music:

```
OSStatus  SoundEngine_LoadBackgroundMusicTrack(const char* inPath, Boolean inAddToQueue, Boolean inLoadAtOnce)

OSStatus  SoundEngine_LoadEffect(const char* inPath, UInt32* outEffectID)

OSStatus  SoundEngine_LoadLoopingEffect(const char* inLoopFilePath, const char* inAttackFilePath, const char* inDecayFilePath, UInt32* outEffectID)
```

To play them

```
OSStatus  SoundEngine_StartBackgroundMusic()

OSStatus  SoundEngine_StartEffect(UInt32 inEffectID)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers given to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046315/getting-notified-when-a-sound-is-done-playing-in-openal) question are very helpful, since Stormyprods' sound engine is a wrapper for OpenAL

I used the following code:

```
ALint sourceState;
alGetSourcei(soundID, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &sourceState);

if (sourceState != AL_PLAYING)
{
    SoundEngine_StartEffect(soundID);
}
else
{
    printf("already playing sfx %d\n", soundID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet it's not possible due to privacy concerns, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: what if the sound is one loaded by my app? neither is it possible?

Comment: that sounds like a different question, for this one, but maybe you don't need to, what do you need this for, what do you want to do with this information?

Comment: For instance given an array of sound effects loaded by SoundEngine_LoadEffect, that are played when an event is triggered, I'd like to play the ones that are not currently being played, just for variety. Beside, the event that plays the sounds could be trigered at any time, even when a sfx is being played already

Comment: still not having enough experience in this matter, I'd say you have two options, 1- keep track of what you are playing yourself and randomize or ensure variety by choosing from a list (array) 2- you are using the wrong set of api, you need a media player framework that lets you play and stop or pause the playback